# how to skip a module if the module it depends on has no outputs?

Tags: terragrunt

I have a module depending on another, example `terragrunt.hcl` in the depending module:

```
dependency "workspace" {
   config_path = "../workspace"
}

inputs = {
  databricks_resource_id = dependency.workspace.outputs.resource_id
}
```

During `apply` there will always be outputs, but during `destroy` there may not be because I am using `--terragrunt-ignore-dependency-errors` and may run `destroy` multiple times.

If the dependency doesn't have any outputs I want the depending module to be skipped with `run-all`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Did I get it right that you want to end up with `workspace` module destroyed, but without the module that depends on it?

Comment: Yes, that is correct!

Comment: The workflow is not fully clear to me. The thing is the following. You have a `workspace` module and another one, which is depending on it, let's call it `child`.
When you're creating the infra, `workspace` is created and then the output is passed into `child`. When you're destroying the infra, the steps are reversed, `child` is destroyed and then `workspace` follows. So how exactly you intend to run destroy multiple times?